# BigQuery quota for concurrent queries

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We have an application that generates a filters panel based upon the columns that a user has stored. Here is an example:

[image]

These queries run simultaneously, so that we can load the sidebar in one go. Each action on a page leads to N + 1 concurrent queries where N = number of filters on a page. It's quite probable that when >5 users are using the application simultaneously, there will be ["rate exceeded" exceptions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy).

Is there any way to request a way to relax this single quota? Unfortunately, this particular quota would make our application almost inoperable if we were to implement BQ for the backend.

Comment: are you running those queries using users credential or just one (same) service account?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant just one account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you can change quota (you might want to contact your [`sales representative`](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) for this)
Meantime, if you really call all these N+1 queries simultaneously - I see another option which is to combine all those N+1 queries into one query thus reducing total queries volume a lot.
It is not clear from your question what exactly your queries looks like - depending on this making one query can be less or more of challenge - but this is definitely an option

Comment: thanks, I sent an email to them so we'll see if it's possible.

Comment: We've requested Google to lift/raise quotas before, and they've been very accomodating. If you're running some decent workloads through BigQuery, they'll most likely try and help you.

Comment: We simply opened a ticket on our support channel. If you don't have support, then your sales rep is the best person. How big are your BigQuery workloads e.g. how much data are you crunching/storing per month?